# how to copy a text of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I copy need the dynamic text of a spam that is generated by a slider that the user sets. It must be copied to a value of an input.

I tried that, and didnt work:

```
<h4>Valor do consórcio: <span class="slider-value quote-form-element valor-carro1" data-name="Valor | Automóvel" name="Valor" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto">R$ <span id="THAT_VALUE"></span></span>
                            </h4>
<div class="slider" data-slider-min="20000" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-start="23192" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto"></div>

<h4>Seus dados:</h4>
<input type="hidden" id="THAT_FIELD" name="THAT_FIELD" value="" />
<h4>Seus dados:</h4>
<input type="hidden" id="valorcarro" name="valorcarro" value=""  />
```

script

```
$(function(){
var valorcarro = $('#THAT_VALUE').html();
$('#THAT_FIELD').val(valorcarro);
});
```

example in this [page](http://consorciomenegalli.com.br/teste.html) in the button on menu "Simulação".

The script just does not copy because the value is generated later and the user can still change

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an event to fire your code after the slider value has changed. This is how you do it with a bootstrap slider.

```
$('.slider').on('slideStop', function () {
    var valorcarro = $('#THAT_VALUE').text();
    $('#THAT_FIELD').val(valorcarro);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of an element, use `text()`

For example

```
$("span").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @Pamblam's response is better than mine. I was assuming the .slider class was for regular range inputs, which fire the 'change' event when their value changes, but it looks like it is in fact a bootstrap slider, which fires the `slideStop` event instead. Regardless, the code here listens for a change in the slider value, and when it is triggered, takes the text from the `#THAT_VALUE` span (from op's code) and sets the value of the `#THAT_FIELD` field to whatever it is :

```
$(".slider").change(function(){
    var valorcarro = $('#THAT_VALUE').text();
    $('#THAT_FIELD').val(valorcarro);
});
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this was downvoted.  It's what I would have done given the limited information provided in the question.

Comment: I thinks because there's no explanation.. @PLan care to explain please... a code only answer isn't a good idea.

Comment: Actually, @Pamblam's response is better than mine. I was assuming the .slider class was for regular range inputs, which fire the 'change' event when their value changes, but it looks like it is in fact a bootstrap slider, which fires the 'slideStop' event instead.

Regardless, the code here listens for a change in the slider value, and when it is triggered, takes the text from the '#THAT_VALUE' span (from op's code) and sets the value of the '#THAT_FIELD' field to whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.

```
jQuery(function(){ 
    var valorcarro = jQuery('#THAT_VALUE').text();
    jQuery('#THAT_FIELD').val(valorcarro);
});
```